# Python Pandas Memory Loss

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter-notebook

I have got some python/pandas memory-loss-issue when reading pickle files (in a loop) or parquet files.
I tried to analyse by using the memory profiler. Results are the following:

```
Filename: /home/ubuntu/work/a4lbs/src/analyze/load.py

Line #    Mem usage    Increment  Occurences   Line Contents
============================================================
   269    265.2 MiB    265.2 MiB           1   def load():

[…]
290    269.5 MiB      0.0 MiB           1       dataframes = []
   291  13328.4 MiB      0.0 MiB          24       for month in months:
   292                                         
   293                                                 # Try to find data source file and skip it if not present
   294  13289.5 MiB      0.0 MiB          23           picklefilename = partnr + month + "_.pickle.gz"
   295                                         
   296                                         
   297                                                 # Check if cached file exists and is up to date, update otherwise
   298  13289.5 MiB      0.1 MiB          23           picklefilepath = cache.cache_file(input_root_path, pickle_subpath, picklefilename)
   299  13289.5 MiB      0.0 MiB          23           if not len(picklefilepath):
   300                                                     continue
   301                                         
   302                                                 # finally read source file
   303  13289.5 MiB      0.0 MiB          23           log("Reading " + month + " from " + picklefilename + "...", end='')
   304  13289.5 MiB      0.0 MiB          23           dataframes.append(
   305  13289.5 MiB      0.0 MiB          23               pd.read_pickle(
   306  13289.5 MiB      0.0 MiB          23                   picklefilepath,
   307  13328.4 MiB  13058.8 MiB          23                   compression="gzip",
   308                                                     )  ## READ
   309                                                 )
   310  13328.4 MiB      0.0 MiB          23           print(" done.")
   311  14577.0 MiB   1248.6 MiB           1       df_data = pd.concat(dataframes, sort=False)  # merge into 1 dataframe
   312  14382.3 MiB   -194.7 MiB           1       dataframes.clear()
   313                                         
   314  14382.3 MiB      0.0 MiB           1       precipitation_data_filename = partnr + "_precipitation_data.parquet"
   315  14382.3 MiB      0.0 MiB           1       precipitation_data_subpath = "/".join((HERE_weather_subpath, partnr))
   316  14382.3 MiB      0.0 MiB           1       print()
   317  14382.3 MiB      0.0 MiB           1       precipitation_data_filepath = cache.cache_file(input_root_path, precipitation_data_subpath, precipitation_data_filename)
   318  14382.3 MiB      0.0 MiB           1       log("Reading precipitation data from " + precipitation_data_filename + "...", end='')
   319  27918.5 MiB  13536.3 MiB           1       prec_df = pq.read_table(precipitation_data_filepath).to_pandas()
   320  27918.5 MiB      0.0 MiB           1       print(" done.")
```

Basically 2 questions:
Line 307: The array "dataframes" requires 13 GB when reading but
Line 312: when I clear it, I only gain 194 MB. I also tries gc.collect() - did not change the result.
Line 319: Reading-in prec_df requires also 13 GB, but the dataframe itself only needs 5 GB:
[image]

To me it looks like the filereading-process itself requires additional memory which is not given back anymore?

Thanks for any help!
Oliver

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pandas' `memory_usage()` function is not a reliable measure of memory usage. At a minimum you want `deep=True` argument to it, but even then it might not track all memory.

As an alternative to `memory_profiler`, you might try https://pythonspeed.com/fil, which gives you a different view of memory usage. It might make it clearer where exactly the memory is being allocated, among other reasons because it's not tied to just reporting a single module like `memory_profiler` is.